# How do I filter data related to selected field box in my lightning data table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, controller, lightning-datatable, filters, sort

- Hello Guys._ Guys, I have an issue with my lightning datatable
- Current table

[image]

The problem is when I want to show the data with the current broker selected, for example, if I select "Accurate ingredientes" broker, the table only would show the data with that broker (in that image would show nothing).

I tried with the controller and the .js but it is not working
The error that I'm getting is from the filterQuery method in JS, that is a call from a dynamicQuery method in the apex controller, there is where I'm trying to get only the data acording to the broker selected.

HTML

```
    .....more codee
<!--Select broker to show in the table-->
                <lightning-layout-item size="3" flexibility="auto" padding="horizontal-small" class="slds-text-align_left">
                    <lightning-combobox
                        data-id = "Broker"
                        name="Broker"
                        label="Broker"
                        value={brokerSelected}
                        options={brokerOptions}
                        onchange={takeDataFilter}>
                        <!--variant="label-hidden"> -->
                    </lightning-combobox>
                </lightning-layout-item>

                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <template if:true={brokerSumLst}>
                        <div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px; height: 300px;">
                        <lightning-datatable 
                            data-id="brokerTable"
                            data={brokerSumLst} 
                            columns={columns} 
                            key-field="Id" 
                            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                            hide-checkbox-column
                            sorted-by={sortedBy}
                            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                            onsort={takeDataFilter}>
                        </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </div
```

broker_commissionRateController

```
public static String query = 'SELECT Id, Broker__c,Broker_Desc__c , Broker_Rate_Desc__c, Broker_Type__c, Name, CreatedById, Notes__c, OwnerId, Start_Date__c FROM BrokerSummary__c WHERE CreatedDate != NULL';
    public static String order = '';

  @AuraEnabled
    public static List<BrokerSummary__c> getBrokersData(){
        return [SELECT Broker_Desc__c, Broker_Rate_Desc__c, Start_Date__c, Broker_Type__c, Notes__c FROM BrokerSummary__c LIMIT 500];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Broker__c> optionsBrokers(){
        Final String queryBrokers = String.escapeSingleQuotes('SELECT Id, Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c FROM Broker__c WHERE Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c != null ORDER BY Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c ASC');
        Final List<Broker__c> getBrokers = Database.query(queryBrokers);
        return getBrokers;
    }


    /**
    * @description : Create a dynamic query with different values that front send to apex.
    * @param getData Map<String,Object> : Map to send especific values for a dynamic query
    * @return List<SObject> 
    **/
    @AuraEnabled
    Public static List<SObject> dynamicQuery(Map<String,Object> getData){
        Final List<SObject> queryFilter = new List<SObject>();
        try {
            Final Set<String> mapValues = getData.keySet();
            for(String iter : mapValues) {
                switch on iter {
                    when 'Broker' {
                        query += 'AND Broker_Desc__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(String.valueOf(getData.get(iter))) + '\' ';
                    }

                    when 'CreatedDate'{
                        order += (String.isEmpty(order) || String.isBlank(order)) ? ' ORDER BY ' + iter + ' ' + String.valueOf(getData.get(iter)) + ' ' : ', '+ iter + ' '+ String.valueOf(getData.get(iter)) + ' ' ;
                    }

                    when else {
                        throw new AuraHandledException('Error to filtering');
                    }
                }
            }
            query+=order;
            query+= 'LIMIT 500';
            queryFilter.addAll(Database.query(query));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return queryFilter;
    }
more code....
```

JS

```
import getBrokers from '@salesforce/apex/broker_commissionRateController.optionsBrokers';
import getBrokersData from '@salesforce/apex/broker_commissionRateController.getBrokersData';

 @track brokerSumLst;

 //Sorting
    @track sortDirection;
    @track sortedBy;

   //options brokers
    @track listBrokers;
    @track brokerSelected = '';

 connectedCallback() {
        fetchFiles({recordId:this.currentId})
        .then(result=>{
            this.lstAllFiles = result; 
            this.error = undefined;
        }).catch(error=>{
            this.lstAllFiles = undefined; 
            this.error = error;
        })

        this.getOptionsBrokers();
        //this.getOptionsContracts();
        this.getBrokerTypesPicklist();
        this.getOptionsRates();

        this.getBroker();
        this.getSolds();
        
    }


     /*Method to call apex class an recieve a list with randos, iterate over them 
    and change fields to assign data in the table */
    getBroker() {
        getBrokersData()
            .then(data => {
                this.assignBro(data);
                //this.brokerLst = data;//Working well
                this.isLoading = false;
                //eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showSuccessToast('Error showing data', error, 'error');
            });
    }
    
    //1st Table
    assignBro(data) {
        this.lstBrokers = [];
        this.info = data;
        console.dir(data);
        this.info.forEach(rando => {
            let brokerSumObj = {};
            brokerSumObj.Id = rando.Id;
            brokerSumObj.Broker_Desc__c = rando.Broker_Desc__c;
            brokerSumObj.Broker_Rate_Desc__c = rando.Broker_Rate_Desc__c;
            brokerSumObj.Start_Date__c = rando.Start_Date__c;
            brokerSumObj.Broker_Type__c = rando.Broker_Type__c;
            brokerSumObj.Notes__c = rando.Notes__c;
            this.lstBrokers.push(brokerSumObj);
        });
        this.brokerSumLst = this.lstBrokers;
    }



    //Get Brokers for create new records
    getOptionsBrokers() {
        getBrokers()
            .then(result => {
                let options = [];
                result.forEach(customerIter => {
                    let customerObj = {
                        label: String(customerIter.Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c),
                        value: String(customerIter.Sold_to_Broker_1_Desc__c) //customerIter.Id
                    };
                    options.push(customerObj);
                });
                this.listBrokers = options;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.showSuccessToast('Error', error, 'error');
            });
    }

    get brokerOptions() {
        return this.listBrokers;
    }

    takeDataFilter(event) {
        let idFilter = String(event.target.dataset.id);
        switch (idFilter) {
            case 'Broker':
                this.brokerSelected = event.detail.value;
                this.queryMap.set('Broker', this.brokerSelected);
                break;
                
            case 'brokerTable':
                    let fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
                    let sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
                    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
                    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
                    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
                    this.queryMap.set(String(fieldName), this.sortDirection);
                break;

            default:
                this.showSuccessToast('Error showing per broker', 'Option Invalid', 'error');
        }
        this.filterQuery();
    }

    filterQuery() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        let obj = Array.from(this.queryMap).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (
            Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value }) // Be careful! Maps can have non-String keys; object literals can't.
        ), {});
        filterQuery({ getData: obj})
        .then(result => {
            this.assignBro(result);
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.showSuccessToast('Error order in 2nd filter', error, 'error');
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you add the picklist field piece of code? Both html and js handler

Comment: @sanketkumar done, the relevant code was already in the js code jeje

Comment: You say it's not working. Please edit your question to elaborate on this. What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @NickCook It is edited, the error specific is in dynamicQuery method in my apex controller